# Ruby/Rails playing with arrays from multilevel nested associations

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongodb-query, database-performance, embedding

I have nested models, all mongoid documents :

```
class Project { ... has_many :tasks ...}

class Task 
  ... 
  has_many :attributions, class_name: "TaskAttribution"
  belongs_to :project

class TaskAttribution 
  ...
  belongs_to :task 
  belongs_to :user
```

I want to get an array of all TaskAttribution from a given project.

I'm sure I can do it with

```
class Project
  ...
  def attributions
    attris = Array.new
    self.tasks.each do |task|
      task.attributions.each do |attri|
        attris << attri
      end
    end
  end
```

Is the compiler doing any improvements, or should I manually do some eager loading ?

Same thing with an extra level of nesting ? (If I want an array of every user participating to the project)

```
class Project
  ...
  def participating_users
    users = Array.new
    self.tasks.each do |task|
      task.attributions.each do |attri|
        attris << attri.user
      end
    end
    users.uniq
  end
```

EDIT : removed other questions because they were judged too subjective/not in the spirit of StackOverflow

Comment: This is too broad a question for StackOverflow. Your question is "subjective" meaning you "hypothesize" a lot and do not show your actual data or usage pattern. "NoSQL" is really all about "usage patterns" and not "design principles". It's basically what **we** built when the traditional "nth normal form" pattern failed us for performance and scalability due to usage. You need to look at this in a different way. Post "usage" and not theory or design patterns.

Comment: Okay. So maybe just the first two questions ? It's exactly what I'm doing in practice.

Comment: I did say "too subjective". It is still. Walking away unless there is an edit to make a distinctive "question". Which BTW is what you can do "on topic". Just One.

Comment: Is there a better StackExchange place where I could ask/find answers to those type of questions ?

Comment: (programmers.stackexchange.com)[http://programmers.stackexchange.com] is a bit more loose to the subjects that can be kicked around. It's better as keep it to "a specific question" with "a definitive answer" on StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks. I'll post there eventually. I have also edited my question, I hope it's better now.